# Streaming audio for iOS with multiple views

Tags: ios, audio, streaming

I'm building and audio streaming app. I found a lot of libraries that can play audio from an URL, but I can't get it work as intended. I Have an slide menu with different views. In the first view I have the player controls. After I leave that view, the player stops, and if I go back, the audio player is reseted. Is there a way to make the audio player work between different views? (Or suggest a library that can do it)

Comment: You have a variable containing the audio player in the first view, you have to put the variable in a 'genera' class or make it >static< to make sure it's not deallocated when the view that started the playback is deallocated

Comment: is it good to use a singleton in this case?

Comment: Well. I would probably use a singleton, but not just for this audio player but for all audio player that you use in your app. To make sure you have full control - no matter where you are in your code.